# Associative algebra generated by Im(a) and Im(b)

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am a complete novice and I am reading "The Octonions" by Baez.

One claim is that in a nicely normed and alternative algebra $A$, that for $a,b \in A$, the algebra generated by $\text{Im}(a)$ and $\text{Im}(b)$ already contains $a,a^*, b, b^*$.

If I look at $\mathbb{C}$, this seems pretty clear, but I wasn't able to show it in the abstract sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $\mathbb{R}$-subalgebras, so any subalgebra would contain the scalars $\mathbb{R}$ which are orthogonal to the pure imaginary elements in $\mathrm{Im}(A)$. Thus, if a subalgebra contained $\mathrm{Im}(a)$, it must also contain the real part $\mathrm{Re}(a)\in\mathbb{R}$ no matter what it is, so it contains the sum and difference

$$ a=\mathrm{Re}(a)+\mathrm{Im}(a), \quad a^\ast =\mathrm{Re}(a)-\mathrm{Im}(a). $$

Comment: You are missing $i$. It is imaginary, but we should write it down anyway ;-). And we need to take $\mathbb{C}$-algebras for sure.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't think I'm missing $i$ at all. As I've always encountered it, the imaginary part ${\rm Im}()$ in the general setting of real normed division algebras is simply the orthogonal projection onto the orthogonal complement of the scalars (the copy of $\Bbb R$ in $A$). So for instance in the octonions $\Bbb O$ we would have ${\rm Im}(\ell)=\ell$ with no $i$ involved. Also $\Bbb O$ is not a $\Bbb C$-algebra since there is no central copy of $\Bbb C$ in it (although we can construct an octonion algebra over $\Bbb C$, this isn't really known as "the octonions").

Comment: Looking at the article by Baez he seems to construct $\Bbb O$ using definitions of $\ast$-algebras, but my answer holds just the same: solve for $a$ and $a^\ast$ in terms of real and imaginary parts, since both are available.

Comment: Sorry I was misreading the question. You are right. I was in the world of $\star$-algebras (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/star-algebra).